Split NeoVim window above others
Let's say I've split the screen into 3 vertical windows using :vs twice.
Now, to open a terminal, I use :sp to split horizontally, but it only splits in the window it's currently in.
I'd like to however split it so that it stretches from left to right. The behavior is similar to VSCode, where the console pops up from the bottom.
Is this possible without going for :sp at the beginning?

How about :bo 20sp (change 20 with how many number of lines you want)
